# parsing a list of discrete multidigit integers in java/android

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have code in Android that is generating an output of coordinates in the general form of {ABCD EFGH IJKL ...}. The coordinate groups are separated by a single space only.

I need to access the last 2 digits of each coordinate group and append an "s" to the beginning of each newly created 2 digit coordinate subgroup. So if I have {1234 5678} I'd like result of my parse to be "s34" "s78".

I'm just thinking about the best way to go about doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using regex to split it into a collection of strings and then manipulate it from there.

Comment: nothing yet, don't know where to start. I'm new to java. I assume it's relatively simple syntax

Comment: There are several solutions for this. You could try parsing every digit with Regex and then doing the splitting and merging in your code as @RU92Z suggested, or you could try to build your own regex pattern that could do the trick. First try to play with that first at http://www.regexr.com/. Read this tutorial first http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways you can acomplish this, heres one way:

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sourceString = "{ABCD EFGH IJKL}";
        // Remove brackets...
        String bracketRemoved = sourceString.replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}", "");

        System.out.println("Removed brackets " + bracketRemoved);

        // split by space
        String[] chunks = bracketRemoved.split(" ");

        for (String s : chunks) {
            System.out.println("Processing " + s);

            // substring the last 2 characters of a 4 length String
            System.out.println("s" + s.substring(2, 4));
        }
    }

}
```

Firstly I strip out the brackets using a regex, quick and dirty solution.
Next split by space...
Then for each String I substring from 2-4 and print with a prefix of s.

Output is

```
Removed brackets ABCD EFGH IJKL
Processing ABCD
sCD
Processing EFGH
sGH
Processing IJKL
sKL
```

Be aware, this is pretty basic, and only covers a happy path. You'll need to protect yourself from exceptions thrown if `s` is shorter than 4! But you can do that :)

Comment: Awesome. This looks to be what I want. I'll dig into Regex a bit more too.

Answer (score 1):

Write pseudo-code.  Design data structures.  Transform pseudo-code into working code.  Maybe something like this:

```
Scan the string forward 2 characters.
Write 's'.
Write the next 2 characters.
Write a separator (space or newline).
Scan over space.
Repeat loop.
```

You will have to handle the start or at least the stop with conditionals because they won't quite be like all the other iterations of the loop.